# Create a curve from intersecting plane and mesh

Tags: animation, mesh, bezier-curves, splines

I have the next problem. I need to create a curve from the intersection of this mesh (the slide) and the plane to make a path for a sphere to follow in an animation. Can you give me a guide on how to make this?

[image]

Comment: Isn't it just a semicircle? Why not add a circle and remove half?

Comment: Yes it is, but I plan to make it more complex and a simple semicircle won't do the job.

Comment: If it is always with a plane then *Knife project > Edit Mode > Duplicate intersection edges > Separate them > Convert to Curve*